# Oracle order NULL LAST by default

Tags: database, oracle, sorting

Is there a way to set the **default** order used by Oracle to be *NULL LAST* (or *NULL FIRST*), without have to put it in each query?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

No, there is no way to change [the default behavior of `NULLS FIRST` and `NULLS LAST`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF55368):

> NULLS LAST is the default for ascending order, and NULLS FIRST is the
>   default for descending order.

---

I can't prove it's impossible to change, but I cannot find such a feature in the places it is most likely to be implemented.

**SQL Option** The [manual](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10002.htm) does not mention anything.

**Parameter** None of the nls parameters in `V$PARAMETER` control it: `select * from v$parameter where name like '%nls%';`

**Hidden Parameter** There's no [hidden parameter](http://coskan.wordpress.com/2007/02/06/how-to-view-list-of-hidden-parameters/).  I tried searching for anything
like %null% or %sort%, none of them appear relevant.

**Locale Builder** Oracle allows you to [create your own custom sorting](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/ch13custlocale.htm#i1006766).  It
has a lot of options, but none of them allow you to define how NULLs are sorted.  Setting the Major Sort and Minor Sort numbers really high or low does not
change it (I was hoping that a NULL was implemented as a hard-coded small or large value).  You can set the sort order for 0x0000, which is "NULL", but that's a different type of NULL.

Answer (score 17):

No, there is no way to enable default ordering without using `order by` clause, which allows you put `NULL`s last or first. Here is an example:

1. Ascending ordering

   ```
   SQL> with t1(col) as(
     2    select 1    from dual union all
     3    select 2    from dual union all
     4    select null from dual union all
     5    select 3    from dual
     6  )
     7  select *
     8    from t1
     9  order by col asc nulls last
     10  ;
   ```

   Result:

   ```
     COL
     ------
      1
      2
      3
      null
   ```
2. Descending ordering

   ```
     SQL> with t1(col) as(
      2    select 1    from dual union all
      3    select 2    from dual union all
      4    select null from dual union all
      5    select 3    from dual
      6  )
      7  select *
      8    from t1
      9  order by col desc nulls last
     10  ;
   ```

   Result:

   ```
     COL
     ----------
      3
      2
      1
      null
   ```

Answer (score 3):

`ORDER BY EMPLOYER_NAME DESC NULLS LAST`

The above worked for me on Oracle 11g

Answer (score 2):

In ascending order, NULL values will always be sorted last

Comment: and in descending order?

Comment: If the null ordering is not specified then the handling of the null values is:
- NULLS LAST if the sort is ASC
- NULLS FIRST if the sort is DESC
- If neither ascending nor descending order is specified, and the null ordering is also not specified, then both defaults are used and thus the order will be ascending with NULLS LAST.

Answer (score 1):

### COALESCE Function

I'm surprised no one yet mentioned it but you can use `COALESCE` function that takes first non-null value out of the arguments. Available in most DBMS:

```
SELECT [Name], [Email] FROM Users
ORDER BY COALESCE([Name], 'zzz')
```

Basically how this works: if [Name] is `null`, the function will return 'zzz' pushing the record down. It does the trick in most scenarious. Documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: thank you for the response, but still you have to put it in each query.
Is this better than doing a `ORDER BY Name NULLS LAST`?

Answer (score 0):

To put the **null** at the end but still **order by asc**:

```
SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY -created_at desc;
```

[Answer Source](https://www.singlestore.com/forum/t/how-to-order-by-with-nulls-comes-first-or-last/386)

Answer (score -2):

we can use like .. Order by col1 desc nulls last, col2 desc. We can use COALESCE as well however, it wont be helpful if we have different datatypes columns like one is date and other is number.

Comment: Do I have to add them on every query that I write?

Comment: Yes, whenever we need order by will have to add it

Comment: yes, but the question was about how to not have to write it in on every query